# Destroy fullcalendar on bootstrap tabs click before new calendar is initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have two tabs from bootstrap. Fullcalendar is inside the second tab which is by default hidden. So I use the onclick event to trigger the `calendar_view_session` function. But every time I visit that tab the new calendar appends in the same tabs. Its actually duplicating the calendar.

```
        calendar_view_session: function(){
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction' , 'momentTimezone' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: false,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events:  function(info, successCallback,failureCallback) {
            console.log(info);

            var date1 = new Date(info.start.valueOf());
            var date2 = new Date(info.end.valueOf());

            var callData = {
                from_date:moment.tz(date1, timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                to_date: moment.tz(date2, timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
            sessionCalendar = [];
            console.log(callData);
            $.ajax({
                  url:app.createApiPath(apiController_data,apiAction_data),
                  method:"POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {
                        callData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(callData)),
                        api_version: 1,
                        deviceType: 'web'
                    },
                  success: function(responseData){
                    console.log({responseData})
             successCallback(app.calendarParse(responseData.data.results));

                }
            })

          },
          //sessionCalendar
    });

    calendar.render();

},
```

My HTML code

```
      <div>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#list_view_session" aria-controls="list_view_session" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">List View</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#calendar_view_session" id="calendar_view_session_id" onclick="app.calendar_view_session()" aria-controls="calendar_view_session" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Calendar View</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="list_view_session">


        <div class="session_list">
          <div class="loaderapi hide">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="calendar_view_session">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

This is my function. However, I use `$("#calendar").destroy()` function to destroy the calendar first. It shows error saying

`sessions.js:253 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).destroy is not a function`

I use this destroy function after

`var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');` line.

Comment: Could you provide some of the HTML as well?

Comment: added html also.

Comment: Would it not be better to create the calendar once outside the tab session code? Then you don't have to destroy and re-create it every time the tab is shown, that seems inefficient. You might need to re-render it each time potentially, but that's less costly than starting from scratch

Comment: That's a good idea :) let me try... That tabs need to be visible first.

Comment: It does work perfectly. I just simply made the calendar tab visible and after initializing of calendar I simply show the first div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the destroy method on `calendar` rathern then on the element in the DOM.

Try to use `window.calendar.destroy()` instead.

Have a look at the docs here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/destroy

Comment: It gave me this error. ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined`  I use that code beore `    var calendarEl = ....`

Comment: Try with this: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'destroy' ), as @radonirina-maminiaina  suggested! This should work!

Comment: I did try with that also. But my fullcalendar version is 4 and the one he suggested is of version 3 which is not supported and throw error.

Comment: Mmmh.. Maybe you are not accessing the global var, dunno why. Try doing this: `window.calendar.destroy()`. Where are you launching the function? Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: `calendar` refers to my element name `<div id="calendar"></div>` Also I see that if I placed the destroy function in the middle of the code or after the success and before success callback it is working. I mean it destroys the calendar and my output is 0. I must say that the destroy function is not working before I initiate the calendar. This is what happening. I am not sure where is the correct place to put that `$("#calendar").destroy()`.

Answer (score 5):

The error is clear, the method destroy doesn't exist into fullcalendar, instead, you do:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'destroy' );
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5opqum4/)

**Update:**

Before you instantiate fullcalendar, you probably need to empty the container element everytime you click your tab.

```
$('#calendar').html('');
```

In your case you do:

```
calendar_view_session: function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    $('#calendar').html('');
    // your long code goes here...
    calendar.render();
}
```

**NB**: You may need timeout to render your calendar.

**Final update**

```
// very global, outside of your context:
var calendar = null;

calendar_view_session: function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        if (calendar) {
            calendar.destroy();
        }
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ... });
        calendar.render();
},
```

Comment: I am using fullcalendar version 4. So this is not supported. It throws error like `sessions.js:143 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue but I am wondering why that destroy is not working. If I placed the destroy function in the middle of the code or after the success and before success callback it is working. I mean it destroys the calendar and my output is 0. I must say that the destory funciton is not working before I initiate the calendar. This is what happening. I am not sure whhere is the correct place to put that `$("#calendar").destroy()`.

Comment: because jQuery Object `$('#calendar')` don't have the instantiation of your fullcalendar.
You should use `calendar.destroy()` because your calendar variable contains the instance of Fullcalendar

Comment: that doesn't work too. Tried already. that calendar is simply returning my element.

Comment: Happy my answer help you! ^^