# FullCalendar v4.2.0 destroy() not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/destroy

FullCalendar Code:

```
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {           
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],                
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            navLinks: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            draggable: true,                
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, 
            events: [
                <?= $contents ?>
            ],                
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
```

FullCalendar v4.2 destroy is not working
I tried the below,

```
 1. var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    calendarE1.destroy();

 2. $("#calendar).destroy();

 3. calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
    });
    calendar.destroy();
```

These things I tried but nothing helps!.
Note: I am trying to destroy the calendar in ajax success.
**My Objective** is I need to destroy the old events and reinitialize by new events.

Comment: fyi, in your example #1: `calendarEl` is not the same as `calendarE1`

Comment: "My Objective is I need to destroy the old events and reinitialize by new events" ...in that case you do **not** need to destroy the entire calendar. You can just add and remove the events themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can initialize the main Calendar object out of DOMContentLoaded, and utilize it as global within that page like the following code:

```
     var calendar;

     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {           
     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
     calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],                
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            navLinks: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            draggable: true,                
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, 
            events: [
                <?= $contents ?>
            ],                
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
```

Now inside any other function you can call it to destroy as follow:

```
if (calendar) {
   calendar.destroy();
}
```

Another option is to use "refetchEvents" as stated in This link:
[how to refresh fullcalendar v4 after change events object using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929421/how-to-refresh-fullcalendar-v4-after-change-events-object-using-ajax)

And this link may also help you : 
[Destroy fullcalendar on bootstrap tabs click before new calendar is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902193/destroy-fullcalendar-on-bootstrap-tabs-click-before-new-calendar-is-initialized)

Comment: It's working fine, I followed the first method. Thank you so much.